# a SSRS 2008 problem:

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created a SSRS report using Sql server 2008 R2.
It is possible to show a user define button in the SSRS 2008 user interface apart from view Report button which is byDefault. Actually i  want to show two button there and show different criteria based on the selection made by a user .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use the ReportView control in your application (and use your ownbuttons and parameters) then no. You are stuck with with SSRS gives you.

In this case it sounds like you need one of

- 2 separate reports
- a report with two sub-reports switched on a parameter
- a linked report to show different parameters

Comment: I just want Two button control on my Report

Comment: @Vikram SE: SSRS does not support this. Sorry.